# Pagination ankle double right click with python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pagination

I need to click on ankle double right button to go the next page. but not able to find the element details as it is changing everytime. below is ankle double right element. not able to find element for this one.
Note: here pg = 7 and pg = 2 are the position of ankle double right button that i understood.

```
<ul class="pagination d-flex align-items-center justify-content- 
between my-5 mb-md-0">Showing 1 to 25 of 194 | <li class="current"> 
<b>1</b></li>
<li class="page-item"><a href="?pg=2" data-page="2">2</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a href="?pg=3" data-page="3">3</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a href="?pg=2" data-page="2"><span class="fa 
fa-angle-double-right  p-2 px-2"></span></a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a href="?pg=8" data-page="8">Last</a></li> 
</ul>


<ul class="pagination d-flex align-items-center justify-content- 
between my-5 mb-md-0">Showing 25 to 50 of 194 | <li class="page- 
item"><a href="?pg=1" data-page="1"><span class="fa fa-angle- 
double-left p-2 px-2"></span></a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a href="?pg=1" data-page="1">1</a></li>
<li class="current"><b>2</b></li><li class="page-item"><a href="? 
pg=3" data-page="3">3</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a href="?pg=4" data-page="4">4</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a href="?pg=3" data-page="3"><span class="fa 
fa-angle-double-right  p-2 px-2"></span></a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a href="?pg=8" data-page="8">Last</a></li> 
</ul>

<ul class="pagination d-flex align-items-center justify-content- 
between my-5 mb-md-0">Showing 50 to 75 of 194 | <li class="page- 
item"><a href="" data-page="">First</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a href="?pg=2" data-page="2"><span class="fa 
fa-angle-double-left p-2 px-2"></span></a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a href="?pg=1" data-page="1">1</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a href="?pg=2" data-page="2">2</a></li>
<li class="current"><b>3</b></li><li class="page-item"><a href="? 
pg=4" data-page="4">4</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a href="?pg=5" data-page="5">5</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a href="?pg=4" data-page="4"><span class="fa 
fa-angle-double-right  p-2 px-2"></span></a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a href="?pg=8" data-page="8">Last</a></li> 
</ul>

<ul class="pagination d-flex align-items-center justify-content- 
between my-5 mb-md-0">Showing 75 to 100 of 194 | <li class="page- 
item"><a href="" data-page="">First</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a href="?pg=3" data-page="3"><span class="fa 
fa-angle-double-left p-2 px-2"></span></a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a href="?pg=2" data-page="2">2</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a href="?pg=3" data-page="3">3</a></li>
<li class="current"><b>4</b></li><li class="page-item"><a href="? 
pg=5" data-page="5">5</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a href="?pg=6" data-page="6">6</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a href="?pg=5" data-page="5"><span class="fa 
fa-angle-double-right  p-2 px-2"></span></a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a href="?pg=8" data-page="8">Last</a></li> 
</ul>
```

I am trying with below code using xpath. but its throwing error as no such element.

I was printed the text of this below element, but ankle double right is not appeared.

```
while bool_value:
 try:
     print('Page Number: ', count)
     if count ==3:
         count+=3  
     driver.find_element(By.XPATH, //ul[@class="pagination d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between my-5 mb-md-0"]/li[@class="page-item"]/a[@data-page="{count}"]/span[@class="fa fa-angle-double-right  p-2 px-2"]).click()  
                         
     count+=1
     time.sleep(1)

 except Exception as msg:
     print('Error:', msg)
     bool_value = False
```

But getting error as element not found, element not clickable etc.,